# Getting user's own phone number information after granting address book request

Tags: ios, abaddressbook

Is there is a way—after an user has granted `Address Book` permission—to get the current user's address and phone number information?

There are various questions on Stack Overflow that focus on this, but I noticed that most of them have been related to either getting data downloaded from [all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081433/store-users-contacts-in-nsmutable-array-after-access-is-granted-for-address-book) contacts, or methods that have been [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-ios) by Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get the user's own phone number or address in iOS. Like you said, there were some ways we can fetch those details before but Apple restricts them from iOS 4 onwards.